# react-native-implementation.js module does not exist in the module map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, react-native-ios

I have installed react native project and install 'react-native-firebase' inside my project. after installation and setting up the project. it's shows react-native-implementation.js module does not exists.

I've already follow the instruction from their site and search, but still no luck.

[This Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akIQv.png)

My package.json

```html
{
 "name": "firebaseApp",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "test": "jest"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
  "react-native": "0.47.1",
  "react-native-firebase": "^2.1.2"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
  "jest": "20.0.4",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
 },
 "jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
 }
}
```

My podfile

```html
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'firebaseApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for firebaseApp
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase'

  # pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  # pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  # pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  # pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  # pod 'Firebase/Database'
  # pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  # pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  # pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  pod "Yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'BatchedBridge', # Required For React Native 0.45.0+
    'Core',
    'ART'
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]

  target 'firebaseApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'firebaseAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

# target 'firebaseApp-tvOS' do
#   # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
#   # use_frameworks!
#
#   # Pods for firebaseApp-tvOS
#
#   target 'firebaseApp-tvOSTests' do
#     inherit! :search_paths
#     # Pods for testing
#   end
#
# end
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: please check this directory from your project node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART and check if ReactNativeART.js available there, if the file not there, try to delete your node_modules and rerun npm install / yarn

Answer (score 3):

1. Close the terminal
2. Rerun npm install
3. Start packager again : react-native run android/ios.